# Altium Designer - split plane

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, layout

I want to make a plane for my supply on my PCB and a plane for my MCU to isolate the MCU from the power supply noise.

I found this article in Altium designer [resource](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Internal+Power+and+Split+Planes):

But it isn't clear how the split plane tool work. Can someone explain it in a different manner?

[EDIT]

This is a picture how I see the planes:
[image]

Comment: Which particular task did you have trouble with?

Comment: Defining the region, I can't properly set the internal plane.

Comment: easy.. just draw a closed shape and double click it to tie a net

Comment: With the polygon pour tool?

Comment: Yes, with the polygon pour tool I think it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on **Place Polygon Plane** ( [image] ). On the dialog, in the **Net Options** select the specific net to which your component is connected.

[image]

Then draw the desired shape for your polygon(s).

[image]